# How to disable the logger in script/console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, irb

In my .irbrc file I require 'logger' to allow me to see the SQL executed when querying ActiveRecords all while in the script/console.

My question is, how do I **temporarily** turn off the logger so it doesn't display the SQL just for a few ActiveRecord queries?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To toggle logging in script/console here's what I use:

```
def show_log
  change_log(STDOUT)
end

def hide_log
  change_log(nil)
end

def change_log(stream, colorize=true)
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ::Logger.new(stream)
  ActiveRecord::Base.clear_all_connections!
  ActiveRecord::Base.colorize_logging = colorize
end
```

Comment: Cool, I like this! Though for Rails 3, you need to take out the last line of the change_log method. Also, returning a nil for that method will give a cleaner "toggle" output.

Answer (score 1):

you can turn off your logger by running in production mode or by adjusting your logger file in `development.rb` environment file in your config directory if you are in fact running in development on your localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am after a temporary solution while in the script/console. e.g. I am in the script/console and am working away with the need for the logger, but then I want to stop the logger from displaying the SQL just for one AR query I am about to run. How would I turn off the logger, and then turn it back on all while in script/console?

Comment: yeah, I saw that after I posted it. I don't know how to do it just for a few sql lines :(

Comment: check the `scripts` folder in you rails app, I think you can turn off the logger for `console` use.